# Bundler not loading gems for script/console in custom environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, console, environment, bundler

I have a Rails 2.3 application with a custom staging environment I created by putting a `staging.rb` file in `environments/`. My staging environment is configured to start the application using that environment. I'm using Bundler to manage gem dependencies as described [here](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html), and I have a gem (that I'm pulling directly from git, if that matters) set up to load in the development and staging environments.

When I start the application in the staging environment, it works fine, including the parts that are dependent on that gem. However, when I try to use the Rails console (`script/console staging`), I get the following error:

```
<snip>site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sanitize_email (MissingSourceFile)
```

It seems like the boot and preinitializer hooks for Bundler are working for the application itself in any environment, but that they're not running properly for the Rails console in the new custom environment.

Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to execute it in bundler's context:

```
bundle exec script/console
```